# Add icon to table sort using php?

Tags: php

I have a simple up and down arrow that I wish to add to the clicked TH and display relevant arrow depending on the sorting:

Here is the code I have at the moment without icons:

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
$sorting = $_GET['sort'];

// check the last sort type used
$sort = ($_SESSION['last_sort_type'] == 'DESC') ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM routes ORDER BY $sorting $sort");

// store it in session.
$_SESSION['last_sort_type'] = $sort;
} else if (!isset($_GET['sort'])) {
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM routes _");
}
```

If you need the actual HTML I can supply it upon request.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is vague. Can they click on various columns to change the order or just one? If more than 1, you'll need [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) or a library specifically designed for this, like [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/).

Comment: I dont want to use datatables for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event to your column, when you are creating your column do something like this,

```
  <td > <a href="#" class="click_me"  >Column-name <span name="desc"><img src="desc.png" width="15" height="15" /><span> </a></td>
```

the span will hold what event you applied , and i assume that the record you fetch will come from server side

now use a little jquery to change your image

```
$(".click_me").on("click",function(){
  var obj =  $(this);
  if(obj.find("span").attr("name")=="desc"){
    obj.find("span").attr("name","asc");
   obj.find("img").attr("img","asc.png");
 }
 else {
       obj.find("span").attr("name","desc");
      obj.find("img").attr("img","desc.png");
 }
// perform your ajax request here, 
// or place the above code inside your ajax success 
});
```

I think you need this kind of thing